# Locating items in a nested list and decoding a ciphercode in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, grid, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search nested list grid and give lettered coordinates in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172229/how-to-search-nested-list-grid-and-give-lettered-coordinates-in-python)

I currently have this nested list acting as a 6x6 grid:

```
grid = [["Z","9","G","Q","T","3"],
        ["Y","8","F","P","S","2"],
        ["X","7","E","O","R","1"],
        ["W","6","D","N","M","0"],
        ["V","5","C","L","K","U"],
        ["J","4","B","I","H","A"]]
```

The rows and columns are referred to as A,B,C,D,E,F rather than the usual 0,1,2,3,4,5. Therefore the letters need to be converted to numbers and then the item has to be found in the nested list.

For example if the user typed in: FE CC ED ED CD
This should locate the letters for HELLO and print out the word HELLO as this was the encrypted message.

Any help on how I manage this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know how to convert a letter to the equivalent number, you can do `ord(letter) - ord('A') + 1`. The rest should be easy. Is there something else you're having trouble with?

Comment: Thought about using a loop that goes through each character and then when it gets the character, use an IF statement to convert back to numbers and then use those as coordinates to find the item in the grid and then print the found item out. Seems like I am doing it a very long way round though and confused myself with all the variables that I will need

Comment: @abernert This would result in 1 for 'A' but apparently he wants the numbers to access the characters in his grid. That means that 'A' has to be mapped to 0.

Comment: @GeorgeSa: Yeah, in my answer I gave 0-based instead of 1-based. Apparently half of the people who jumped to be the first to convert my comment into an answer hoping for easy rep didn't catch that. :)

Comment: Yes @tcaswell, a duplicate of his own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> input_string = "FE CC ED ED CD"

# Convert input string into integers
# `ord()` converts 'A' to 65, 'B' to 66, etc
>>> pairs = [tuple(ord(letter) - ord('A') for letter in pair) for pair in input_string.split()]
[(5, 4), (2, 2), (4, 3), (4, 3), (2, 3)]

# Now just retrieve the tuples from the list of pairs
# And look up the index in the grid
>>> output = ''.join(grid[x][y] for x, y in pairs)
'HELLO'
```

Comment: `.split()` splits on whitespace by default, so you can omit the `' '` argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks - saved me three characters :)

Comment: It does more than that: initial and trailing whitespace is skipped, and multiple whitespace characters count as one split position.

Comment: Oh, and your `tuple()` call to create the pairs is not really needed, you could just as well make it a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Without the `tuple` call they were converting to generators, it was a quick and easy fix.

Comment: Using `[ord(letter) - ord('A') for letter in pair]` would have been the other. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah yes, but I wanted to output a list of tuple pairs ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mapping to turn letters to numbers. Such a mapping is easy to generate from the `string.ascii_uppercase` string:

```
import string
letter_to_index = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}
```

Using `letter_to_index` it is then trivial to turn a letter (e.g. `E`), into a number (`4`):

```
>>> letter_to_index['E']
4
```

Using a space-separated input, this becomes:

```
letters = []
for coordinate in code.split():
    row, column = letter_to_index[coordinate[0]], letter_to_index[coordinate[1]]
    letters.append(grid[row][column])

print ''.join(letters)
```

Other techniques use `ord()` to get the ASCII ordinal for a letter (subtract `ord('A')` to make it 0-based) or using `.index()` on `string.ascii_uppercase` (which would be slower).

Comparing their relative speed with the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is the best way to figure out which one is the fastest technique (if you so care):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def lookup_map(coordinate):
...     return letter_to_index[coordinate[0]], letter_to_index[coordinate[1]]
... 
>>> def lookup_ord(coordinate, orda=ord('A')):
...     return ord(coordinate[0]) - orda, ord(coordinate[1]) - orda
... 
>>> def lookup_index(coordinate, upper=string.ascii_uppercase):
...     return upper.index(coordinate[0]), upper.index(coordinate[1])
... 
>>> coords = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase[:6])+random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase[:6]) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> timeit.timeit('[lookup(c) for c in coords]', 'from __main__ import coords, lookup_map as lookup', number=10000)
3.883746862411499
>>> timeit.timeit('[lookup(c) for c in coords]', 'from __main__ import coords, lookup_ord as lookup', number=10000)
4.582481861114502
>>> timeit.timeit('[lookup(c) for c in coords]', 'from __main__ import coords, lookup_index as lookup', number=10000)
9.782031059265137
```

The dictionary (mapping) approach is fastest; using `ord()` is close behind (if you compute `ord('A')` only once), and using `.index()` takes almost three times as long.

Comment: Why map it to a `list` index instead of just using `ord`?

Comment: @abarnert: It's one technique; using `ord` is another. No other reason. For a *large* number of coordinates, the mapping would be faster.

Comment: Using index would not be slow. You're searching through a `list` where you're guaranteed to only need to look at the first 6 elements, and on average 3.5 of them.

Comment: @abarnert: Not a good practice to teach beginners; for this *specific* case it'll be not much slower.

Comment: According to `timeit`, it's actually 1.6x faster. But `ord` is 12x as fast as that. And I think teaching people "`list`s are slow, `dict`s are fast" is actually a bad lesson if you don't take into account the fact that for small connection, `list`s are actually faster. (And it stands to reason that `ord` is going to be much faster than looking up the letters in either a list _or_ a `dict`.)

Comment: @abarnert: I've included `timeit` statistics. `ord()` is nowhere that fast. I think you did something wrong in your tests.

Comment: I just looked up 10M random letters from `A` through `F` with each of three methods. Note that by choosing `EF` (which are toward the end of the range) you've unfairly biased things against the `list` implementation.

Comment: @abarnert: I tried it with `AF` too, to get an average. Same (relative) results. Just ran it with 1000 random two-letter coordinates (picked from A to F) and the relative results are still the same. I've updated my answer with those latter results.

Comment: @abarnert: Interestingly enough, Python 3.3 takes even longer for the `.index()` case (and `ord()` is a bit slower still too). The `.index()` case is *5 times* slower than using a mapping.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on 32-bit? 3.3 seems a lot slower than 2.7 for various random things in 32-bit builds… often in the same places it's faster in 64-bit builds. At least on Mac and Linux. Anyway, I think we're getting way off topic for the OP's question here…

Comment: @abarnert: This is 64-bit 3.3 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

```
def letter_to_number(letter):
    return ord(letter.upper()) - ord('A')
```

This reason this works is that `ord(x)` returns the value of character `x` in whatever your character set is—and, whether that's ASCII, Latin-1, UTF-8, or something else, the letters all come in order.

You can see this by experimenting with it in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> ord('B')
66
>>> ord('F')
70
>>> ord('F') - ord('A')
5
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the characters to integers you could do this:

```
def char_to_num(char):
    return ord(char)-ord('A')
```

To access the characters in your grid, you would do something like this (I assume the input is referred to as `input`):

```
word = ""
for position in input.upper():
   word += grid[char_to_num(position[0])][char_to_num(position[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index=input('Enter the index:')
index=list(index)
a=[ord(i)-ord('A') for i in index]
print(grid[a[0]][a[1]])
```